# Как вывести html код ТЕКСТОМ?

Tags: php, html

нужно вывести html код в виде текста, каким образом это сделать что этот самый код - не превратился в изображение, а остался текстом при выводе?)

```
echo  '<img src="images/img.png">';
```

Вот нужно именно вот это вывести

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте функцию [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<img src="images/img.png">');
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно оборачивать скобки тегом

```html
echo  '<span><</span>img src="images/img.png"<span>></span> ';
```

Comment: Это неправильный подход в принципе. "Угловые скобки" нужно заменять на сущности для их вывода в браузер "как есть"

Comment: Я рекомендовал с позиции что проще оборачивать "угловые скобки" в спан чем запоминать шифры "сущностей", при этом код не теряет в читабельности как с "сущностями".

Comment: Это может быть и проще, но 1. плодит лишний код; 2. получаем невалидный код; который может выводиться в браузер либо как мы ожидаем либо с ошибками

Comment: 1) На PHP можно функцию выше использовать, но на голом HTML предложенный код, помогающий решить задачу не может стать лишним.
2) Едва ли тег созданный для оформления текста, может повлиять на валидность при его использовании для оформления текста.

Comment: Тег не влияет. На валидность влияет наличие неэкранированных знаков `<`, `>` и `&` и единственно правильный метод их экранирования в html - замена на сущности